# OpenGL control in WPF - how to?

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl

I need to use OpenGL in my WPF project. I'd prefer it to be as simple in installation as possible, but I'm beginning to lose hope.

I've tried **SharpGL**: it's pretty good and easy to use, but it has massive memory leaks and the app crashes after few seconds. Not very useful.

So now I am wondering: is there an alternative to this library? Actually I don't have to use OpenGL - I just need to present a 3D scene in any technology .. perhaps D3D or something else will be easier to manage in WPF...

What do you recommend?

Kind regards

Q.

---

Update: Yes, I'm working under Windows 7. And I'd really prefer smt. OpenGL based because I already know the technology.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible because as I know WPF is based on D3D.

Answer (score 0):

Within WPF, I can easily say that using [XNA](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) will be the easiest way, which many people have done before. There's even an example project here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2011/03/25/wpf-hosting-for-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Tao framework supports this: [taoframework-2.1.0-setup.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/files/The%20Tao%20Framework/2.1.0/taoframework-2.1.0-setup.exe/download)

Once you've installed it, right click on your Toolbar and select "Choose Items.." and add "SimpleOpenGlControl" from the .NET Framework Components list. If you can't find it in the list, hit browse and search for Tao.Platform.Windows.dll in your Tao Framework installation directory.

After that you can just drag the OpenGl control wherever you like, and use its Paint event to do your stuff in. (Not really sure how often that event fires though, last time I checked it fired once every 12 seconds or something so you may need to do some magic stuff to have it fire more often - say a thread to call Draw, or some other nifty stuff)

Answer (score 0):

I have used successfuly OpenTK library (http://www.opentk.com/).
Works with WPF/Windows Forms.