# Confused about XNA (is it just a Direct3D wrapper?)

Tags: wpf, xna

I have an industrial C#/WPF application written that needs to render thousands of 3D lines.  (N.B. these are not a wireframe -  they do not necessarily represent a 3D surface, so I don't want to tesselate polygons into triangles, or do lighting a shading, but I **do** want hardware acceleration) I've been looking at OpenGL and Direct3D but I keep seeing XNA suggested on Stack Overflow, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463523/opengl-control-in-wpf-how-to) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765841/wireframe-rendering-in-wpf)

I went to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA to try to understand it but I'm still confused.  Is it just a wrapper for something I should be using directly, like Direct3D?  Does it give me access to the underlying graphics API?  Can it even do lines?  Can I run it in a WPF object like a Panel or Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it just a wrapper for something I should be using directly, like Direct 3D

XNA is not a 1:1 of DirectX.

Though XNA uses DirectX under the hood it's generally not correct to think of it as *"just a wrapper"* for DirectX.  XNA does a few things that DirectX doesn't, like *content pipelines*; a clearly-defined separate game loop and draw point; content load and unload callbacks; and 2D sprites. (Microsoft ditched 2D drawing DirectDraw for a time and only now have released Direct2D)

XNA consists of a series of layers starting with *Platform* being the lowest and includes APIs such as Direct3D 9; XACT; and XInput.

Building upon Platform you'll find *Core Framework; Extended Framework*; and *Games* which abstract; encapsulate the lower layers whilst adding new features that result in *"making game development easier"*. [1]

The end result is so far removed from DirectX (except perhaps for the shaders) you would not be aware you are using DirectX.  You can have a game window up and running in a few lines of code compared to DirectX's pages and pages of code.

> Does it give me access to the underlying graphics API?

If you mean can you talk directly to DirectX COM API then no, you can't.  You can however write shaders that when compiled, the GPU will understand indirectly.

> Can it even do lines?

Yes.

> Can I run it in a WPF object like a Panel or Canvas?

[Apparently so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4121601/585968).  I should point out that WPF *already* is hardware accelerated and uses DirectX for rendering.  Even those *drop shadow* effects you see in WPF are actually DirectX GPU shaders.

### Today

As you have probably read, XNA is deprecated and though Monogame is *active* is not 100% compatible with XNA (just look for the many posts on SO regarding XNA Content Pipeline issues for one).

Therefore if you are wishing to do 3D in **WPF**, well **you don't need XNA** for that.

### More

[1] Cookiecups, *"[what is the xna framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xna/archive/2006/08/25/what-is-the-xna-framework.aspx)"*, MSDN Blogs

Comment: I and many others have posted questions on Stack Overflow asking about using WPF to draw 3D lines in a hardware-accelerated way and the consensus seems to be that WPF has no such ability.  Most of the solutions seem to involve creating really thin polyhedrons to simulate lines and many of the formalized solutions, e.g., Helix, have been shown to produce weird artifacts.  If it is possible to draw 3D lines in WPF could you please link to an example?

Comment: @user316117  _"using WPF to draw 3D lines in a hardware-accelerated way and the consensus seems to be that WPF has no such ability"_ - well they would be incorrect. _"[The 3-D functionality in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) enables developers to draw, transform, and animate 3-D graphics in both markup and procedural code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747437(v=vs.100).aspx)"_.  WPF uses DirectX behind the scenes already and you can even create your own shaders for use in a standard WPF app.  Follow the link provided to see an example

Comment: @user316117 One thing that should be noted, the nature of WPF including WinForms is that neither were designed for _making games_. Now that doesn't mean you can't, it just depends on the _nature of your game_.  However, at least both XNA and WPF are hardware accelerated but only XNA allows your game loop to run at _full throttle_ due to the non-existence of a message pump I would suspect.